# VueJS XHR inside reusable component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Asking for best practice or suggestion how to do it better:

I have 1 global reusable component `<MainMenu>` inside that component I'm doing XHR request to get menu items.

So if I place `<MainMenu>` in header and footer XHR will be sent 2 times.

I can also go with props to get menu items in main parent component and pass menu items to `<MainMenu>` like:

`<MainMenu :items="items">`

Bet that means I cant quickly reuse it in another project, I will need pass props to it.

And another way is to use state, thats basically same as props.

What will be best option for such use case?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to instantiate a new component, but have your main menu in many places you can use `ref="menu"` which will allow you to access it's `innerHTML` or `outerHTML`. I've created an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/31om3nn2w6) to which you can refer.

```
<div id="app">
  <main-menu ref="menu" />
  <div v-html="menuHTML"></div>
</div>
```

`refs` aren't reactive so if you used `v-html="$refs.menu.$el.outerHTML"` it wouldn't work since `refs` are still undefined when the component is created. In order to display it properly you would have to create a property that keeps main menu's HTML and set it in `mounted` hook:

```
data() {
  return {
    menuHTML: ''
  }
},
mounted() {
  this.menuHTML = this.$refs.menu.$el.outerHTML;
}
```

This lets you display the menu multiple times without creating new components but it still doesn't change the fact that it's not reactive.

In the example, menu elements are kept in `items` array. If the objects in `items` array were to be changed, those changes would be reflected in the main component, but it's clones would remain unchanged. In the example I add class "red" to items after two seconds pass.

To make it work so that changes are reflected in cloned elements you need to add a watcher that observes the changes in `items` array and updates `menuHTML` when any change is noticed:

```
mounted() {
  this.menuHTML = this.$refs.menu.$el.outerHTML;
  this.$watch(
    () => {
        return this.$refs.menu.items
    },
    (val) => {
      this.menuHTML = this.$refs.menu.$el.outerHTML;
    }, {
    deep: true
    }
  )
}
```

You can also watch for changes in any data property with:

```
this.$refs.menu._data
```

With this you don't need to pass `props` to your main menu component nor implement any changes to it, but this solution still requires some additional logic to be implemented in it's parent component.